# conditional splitting of string and word by matching characters in js

Tags: javascript, string

I have very long string that contains html as a string , numbers , my special bindings and numbers I want to split my bindings and sentences with spaces separately  but my program is separately my bindings and words .

my js code:-

```
var x = 'hey this is {{name}}    and I love to  {{write}} and to learn as 
much as I can. Now I am trying to separate sentences and my bindings'

var c  = x.match(/\s*\S*\s*/g) // this splits words from string including 
   space

var mt = x.match(/{(.*)}/g); // trying to  take out bindings but this don't 
 work

mt.forEach(function(a){     // taking each bindings separately 
  var z = x.match(a) 
})

console.log(mt)
```

Somthing like this .. but I know this is totally wrong please help me 
I don't have any idea :-

output that I am expecting:-

```
(5) ["hey this is", "i", "{{name}}", "    and I love to  ", "{{write}}", " and to learn as ↵ much as I can. Now I am trying to separate sentences and my bindings"]
```

How can i do this?

Please don't use jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
I've commented my code hoping it would make it easier to read. **But do note that this code is far from perfect although it solves your problem.**

```
var rawString = 'hey this is {{name}}    and I love to  {{write}} and to learn as much as I can. Now I am trying to separate sentences and my bindings';
var arrayRawString  = rawString.match(/\s*\S*\s*/g); // this splits words from string including space
var arrayPlaceholder = rawString.match(/{(.\S*)}+/g); // trying to  take out bindings but this don't work

// to store the final output
var separedArray = [];

// keeping track of the index to stich the array up
var posStart = 0;
var posEnd = 0;

arrayPlaceholder.forEach(function(arg){     // taking each bindings separately 

  // length of the array that holds placeholder (bindings)
  var arsLength = arrayRawString.length;

  for(var i = 0; i < arsLength; ++i) { 

    // if the provided text matches the original array's element
    if(arrayRawString[i].match(arg)){

      // to store the index
      posEnd = arrayRawString.indexOf(arrayRawString[i]);

      // join the pieces together upto the index defined
      var res = arrayRawString.slice(posStart, posEnd).join('');

      // to indicate whether the stored string is the placeholder
      var flag = true;

      // store the string obtained
      separedArray.push(res.replace(arrayPlaceholder[(arrayPlaceholder.indexOf(arg) - 1) < 0 ? 0 : arrayPlaceholder.indexOf(arg) - 1 ], ''));

      // check if the string still has placeholder (bindings)
      // to remove it
      for(var j = 0; j < arg.length; ++j) {
          if(res[j] !== arg[j]) {
            flag = !flag;
          }
      }

      if ( flag ) {
        separedArray.push(arg);
      }

      // last end position is the start position for next round
      posStart = posEnd;

      // because the loop runs only arrayPlaceholder.length times
      // it solves the problem of last part not getting pushed to the final array
      if( arrayPlaceholder[arrayPlaceholder.length-1] === arg ) {
        res = arrayRawString.slice(posStart, arrayRawString.length).join('');
        separedArray.push(res.replace(arg, ''));
      }
    }
  }

});

console.log(separedArray);
```